# How to store prices for every pair of objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I'm working on a web app. This app has model `Location` which can be New York, Wienna, Paris etc.

Now I want to have some data structure/table which holds **price** for any tuple from set of `Location` objects.

So if there are 3 objects yet - NY, PA, WI, I have to store **price** for:

```
NY - PA #(since there is NY - PA price, I don't have to store PA - NY which is the same)
NY - WI
PA - WI
```

And I want admin to be able to add/change prices for any tuple.

What should I do? I thought about some grid which would hold information about prices but I don't know how to simulate such grid in `Django admin` and `Django ORM`.

What I've done so far is creation of a model `CityPrice` which looks like this:

```
class CityPrice(models.Model):
    city_one = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='city_tuple')
    city_two = models.ForeignKey(City)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('city_one', 'city_two'),)
```

But as you can see there are multiple problems there. One problem is that cities are not "equal" one has to be `city_one` and one has to be `city_two`. Another problem is that `Admin` would have to open for each tuple new tab in `Django-Admin` and change the price there which is very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

What I think would be nice solution is to have each `Location` model a `ManyToManyField` field, which links to `CityPrice` model. That way many `Location` models will share the same price and you will be able to have multiple prices assigned to a single city.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # your stuff
    price = models.ManyToManyField(CityPrice)
```

You can than get the cities, which share the same price by:

```
price_object.locations.all()
```

More information and examples about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: But one Location hasn't only one price... it has ** number of location objects - 1 ** prices. For each pair. So it would not work this way, wouldn't it?

Comment: In that case use ManyToMany field.